# Only one MySQL Database Works at a time

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, joomla

I installed WordPress at localhost:60 on IIS and MySQL. It worked fine. Then I created a second database on MySQL for Joomla and installed Joomla at localhost:40. Joomla also worked without a problem but when I revisited WordPress, it gave me the following error: **Error establishing database connection**

I checked MySQL and found out that WordPress database still existed. Anyways, I deleted WordPress database and created and new one and re-installed WordPress.

Now WordPress works fine but Joomla gives me database connection error. So this problem alternates between the two.

Anyone knows what is wrong?
Thanks!!

Comment: The webserver is on the same box as mysql?  Make sure your two mysqld instances have different paths for the .sock file.  Stabbing in the dark here, but they might be writing to the same .sock.  It's usually in /var/run/mysqld.sock or something like that

Comment: @FrankFarmer Yes it on the same machine. I think I am running one instance of MySQL. Do I need two?

Comment: I'm confused, you say you're running mysqld on two ports (what does  `localhost:60` and `localhost:40` mean)?  How did you do that?  Maybe post some relevant config?  Honestly, normally in your situation I'd just run mysql on 3306 and create two databases inside with different names.

Comment: @FrankFarmer Oh Sorry! I mean WordPress is on `localhost:60`, Joomla on `localhost:40`. mysql is on `localhost:3306`.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating random ports for IIS!, if you are at least make them high range ports `1024+` Also this question seems off topic for SO, as you are installing / configuring software not programming.

Answer (score 0):

since you're trying to use the same DB with two different CMS the installation of one probably messes the other. since now you have wordpress working, assuming you know the what is the connection string, go to Joomla home and edit configuration.php  and make sure the following parameters are configured correctly (for Joomla 1.5):

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = '<DB username>';
public $password = '<DB password>';
public $db = '<DB scheme>';
```

Comment: I was not trying to use a single database with both wp and joomla. I created a database 'wordpress' for WordPress and another database 'joomla' for Joomla.

Comment: you said above: "I think I am running one instance of MySQL" - so what is it ? one instance or two ? do not confuse DB with Schema!